# Blender Game engine Animation Not playing

Tags: game-engine

The Tux character in the attached blend does not play the walking animation. The parenting is set correctly (armature) and all modifiers have been removed.

Any ideas?

[GoogleDrive Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrH_jF-hxPjMjR5WF81T0dpTTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't open your file from here.

You need at least the armature modifier. You can easily get them by

- select the skin mesh object(s)
- <kbd>shift</kbd> select the armature
- <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> Set Parent To \ Armature Deform

Usually you need Vertex Groups set that match the names of the armature's bones.

<kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> Set Parent To \ Armature Deform \ With ... allows you to create such Vertex Groups.

I hope it helps